# Calculate weekly mean from time series with missing data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, xts, missing-data

I have a time series object with daily values that starts in the 19th century and reaches into the 20th century. There are a lot of missing values in there.

I'm trying to calculate weekly means and here's a minimal example:

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)

# Create time series that starts in 19th century
T <- 100 # number of days
myTS <- xts(rnorm(T), as.Date(1:T, origin="1899-11-05"))

# Insert some missing values
myTS[4:7] <- NA
myTS[33:34] <- NA
myTS[67:87] <- NA

# Try calculating weekly means
weekData <- apply.weekly(myTS, colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
```

which only returns the weekly mean for the last week:

> 1900-02-13  [some value]

I use `colMeans` instead of just `mean` because I'm operating on a larger dataset with several variables.

I would like the mean for all the weeks. Does somebody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated based on your comment to use week-year combination:

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)

# Create time series that starts in 19th century
T <- 100 # number of days
myTS  <- xts(rnorm(T), as.Date(1:T, origin="1899-11-05"))

# Insert some missing values
myTS[4:7] <- NA
myTS[33:34] <- NA
myTS[67:87] <- NA

# Let's use a flexible class
myTS <- data.frame(dates=index(myTS),v1=myTS[,1])

# Here's an easy way to transform dates to weeks
require(lubridate)
week_num <- week(myTS[,1])
year_num <- year(myTS[,1])
week_yr  <- paste(week_num, year_num)

# Weekly means
aggregate(myTS$v1,by=list(week_yr),mean,na.rm=T)
```

> ```
>    Group.1           x
> 1   1 1900  0.05405322
> 2   2 1900  0.31981319
> 3   3 1900         NaN
> 4   4 1900         NaN
> 5  45 1899  0.85081053
> 6  46 1899  0.34064255
> 7  47 1899  0.02880424
> 8  48 1899 -0.34408119
> 9  49 1899 -0.38089026
> 10  5 1900  0.62292188
> 11 50 1899 -0.59666955
> 12 51 1899  0.57756987
> 13 52 1899 -0.41325485
> 14 53 1899  0.88013634
> 15  6 1900  0.01514668
> 16  7 1900 -0.50863942
> ```

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted is not the mean for week1 across years, week2 across years and so on. But I would like the mean for all these weeks separately. So week1_1899, week2_1899, ..., week52_1900, week53_1900.

Comment: Fantastic, that does the job!